# Why isn't my Minecraft LAN server working? Is it because the zip codes are different?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

So I live in a town with 3 different ZIP codes. I'm not sure if ZIP codes have anything to do with Minecraft LAN servers. My problem is that my friend cannot connect to my LAN server. We live at different ends of town so I'm not sure if it is the reason. Could someone explain how the LAN servers work and if it is related to ZIP codes?

Comment: zip codes have nothing to do with LAN

Answer (score 7):

LAN is short for Local Area Network, as in a homenetwork. If you want to set up a LAN server over internet you need to use a virtual LAN network like [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/Hamachi/download.aspx) can provide.

Setting it up is quite easy, just have everyone join the same hamachi network (up to five people on free hamachi) and let them connect to the hamachi IP of the hoster (hamachi IP's begin with a five so 5.x.x.x where the x's can be anything from 0 to 255).

Answer (score 2):

LAN can only work when you are connected to the same network, as said above

Answer (score -1):

If you want to start a LAN server and play with your friend. make sure that your friends are using the same network/wifi, if not, start a server(https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/?ref=bm, in the play with your friends' section, there is a link called "setup your own server",make sure you agreed to the EULA before starting the server there will be a file called EULA.txt) and set a port forwarding, usually Minecraft server's default port is 25565, so go google your IP address(or use www.whatismyIPaddress.com) and send your friend the ip address something like this XX.XX.XX.XX:AAAAA X=Ip address, A=Port

Comment: btw LAN server means Local Area Network, basically the same network, you can think of its a private network only for 1 wifi or something like that, I don't think that it has anything to do with the Zip code...